# I have error can't adapt type 'NewId' error in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have error can't adapt type 'NewId'. Every time I do edit or delete line always show the error

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('product_id','order_id')
def _get_cost_price_currency_update2(self):
    for record in self:
        param2 =()
        query2 = '''SELECT hpp_update,cost_price_set_lock
                        FROM sale_order_line
                        WHERE order_id = %s AND product_id = %s
                 '''
        param2 +=(record.order_id.id,record.product_id.id)
        self.env.cr.execute(query2,param2)
        query_result_lines2= self.env.cr.dictfetchall()

        for line in query_result_lines2:
            if line['hpp_update']:
                cost_price_set_update = line['hpp_update']
            else:
                cost_price_set_update = line['cost_price_set_lock']
            record.cost_price_set_update = cost_price_set_update

cost_price_set_update = fields.Float(string='CPP Update', compute=_get_cost_price_currency_update2)
```

I found another similar question but I con not found the solution. Any help please? Thank you

UPDATE
Base on Andrei suggestion I have made some change in the script like this

```
cost_price_set_lock = fields.Float(string='CPP Lock',compute=_get_cost_price_currency, store=True) 

@api.depends('order_id')
def _get_cost_price_currency_update2(self):
    cost_price_set_update2 = ''
    invoice_pool = self.env['sale.order.line']
    for record2 in self:
        for invoice in invoice_pool.search([('order_id', '=', record2.order_id.id), ('product_id', '=', record2.product_id.id)]):
            if invoice.hpp_update:
                cost_price_set_update2 = invoice.hpp_update
            else:
                cost_price_set_update2 = invoice.cost_price_set_lock
        record2.cost_price_set_update = cost_price_set_update2

cost_price_set_update = fields.Float(string='CPP Update', compute=_get_cost_price_currency_update2)
```

The problem with this is that the value of the cost_price_set_update is always change base on the compute result from cost_price_set_lock field where it should be the one that stored first time.

Comment: Give some more detailed error message, please.  It would help. 
As a side not, I don´t recommend using SQL in this code. You can do it with the ORM methods.